# Issue to handle close red X button in SWT

Tags: java, swt, serversocket

I have a quick question regarding upper right corner red button to close the applications (Windows 7)...
I have programmed a ServerSocket in Java but when I close the application using this close button the server keeps running...
I would like to capture this event (if possible), and ensure that when this button is pressed the whole program including the ServerSocket is closed.

This is the piece of code I think that I have to amend to capture this event...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Server().startServer();
        Window1 window = new Window1();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Listen for `SWT.Close` on your `Display` and shut the server down within this `Listener`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Server().startServer();
        Window1 window = new Window1();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void shutdownServer()
{
    /* Shutdown your server here */
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();

    display.addFilter(SWT.Close, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            shutdownServer();
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can attach a WindowListener to it and put whatever you need to do in the windowClosing() method.

```
public class Test implements WindowListener {
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public Test() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(this);
}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    //handle window closing, close socket, etc
}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

}
```

}

Comment: The question is about `SWT`, not `Swing`.